# Resharper test window shows "aborted" but all tests are passing

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, mstest

I have a set of successful running tests in my suite. For some reason "sometimes" test with test parameters are aborted, even though all tests ran successfully. What can be the reason for this?

I have tried the MS test runner as well and everything is okay.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I just had this issue and fixed it by right-clicking the line that says `Aborted` and click `Clear Test Result`. Then run your tests again and it should be all good.

Comment: Well, that was easy.  NGL, I think that's a bit silly that you have to do that, but...whatevs.  JetBrains, you so crazy...